# How to configure 2-level of hibernate entity cache via annotations properly

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-cache, ehcache-2

I want to configure 2nd level hibernate cache at Spring Boot microservice.
And I don't want to use xml at all.
Next is my example.

UserEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "users")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public UserEntity(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

   // ... geters&setters
}
```

CacheConfig.java

```
import net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration;
import net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStoreEvictionPolicy;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public org.springframework.cache.CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    }

    private net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {

        CacheConfiguration usersCacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
        usersCacheConfiguration.setName("users");
        usersCacheConfiguration.eternal(false);
        usersCacheConfiguration.setMaxEntriesInCache(1000);
        usersCacheConfiguration.setMaxEntriesLocalDisk(0);
        usersCacheConfiguration.memoryStoreEvictionPolicy(MemoryStoreEvictionPolicy.LRU);

        net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();
        config.addCache(usersCacheConfiguration);

        return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(config);
    }
}
```

App.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class)
                .sources(CacheConfig.class)
                .run(args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
  jpa.open-in-view: false
  jpa.properties.javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode: ALL
  jpa.properties.hibernate:
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
    jdbc.batch_size: 100
    temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
    order_inserts: true
    cache:
      region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
      #region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
      #region_prefix: ""
      use_second_level_cache: true
      cache.use_query_cache: true
      provider_class: org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
```

build.gradle

```
group 'com.hibernate.cache'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '5.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-ehcache', version: '5.2.14.Final'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.1.4'
}
```

When I run the program I see a couple of warnings indicating that entity cache configuration is not applied:

```
2018-03-04 23:29:48.723  WARN 8516 --- [           main] n.s.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory  : No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/home/vitaly/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.10.3/cf74f9a4a049f181833b147a1d9aa62159c9d01d/ehcache-2.10.3.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
2018-03-04 23:29:48.834  WARN 8516 --- [           main] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory     : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [users]; using defaults.
```

Does anybody know what is wrong here?

Comment: Found the solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21944585/7022735

Answer (score 1):

The first warning:

```
2018-03-04 23:29:48.723  WARN 8516 --- [           main] n.s.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory  : No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/home/vitaly/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.10.3/cf74f9a4a049f181833b147a1d9aa62159c9d01d/ehcache-2.10.3.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
```

means that no ehcache.xml configuration was found so a default, ehcache-failsafe.xml, is used.

The second warning:

```
2018-03-04 23:29:48.834  WARN 8516 --- [           main] o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory     : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [users]; using defaults.
```

means that there was no configuration found for the "users" region in the cache. It is, of course, not defined in ehcache-failsafe.xml and it doesn't look like the settings in `CacheConfig` are being picked up - at least not by the `CacheManager` used by Hibernate.

It should be possible to solve both by adding an ehcache.xml to the classpath (in `src/main/resources`), e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true"
         monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">

    <cache name="users"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="500"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="300"
           timeToLiveSeconds="600"
           diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="1"
           copyOnRead="true"
           copyOnWrite="true">
        <copyStrategy class="net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.ReadWriteSerializationCopyStrategy" />
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

(see [this ehcache.xml sample](http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xml) for more options)

And adding the following to application.yml:

```
spring:
  cache:
    ehcache:
      config: classpath:ehcache.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. But can I do the same without xml?

Answer (score 0):

A year late but the answer to your question might require you to implement your own RegionFactory class (by extending SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory) And then set your newly created class as the factory that hibernate should use: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=com.my.class
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28594371/708854