# Hibernate configuration equivalent of ehcache.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, configuration, ehcache

Is there any Hibernate configuration equivalent of `ehcache.xml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using EhCache in Spring 4 without XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944202/using-ehcache-in-spring-4-without-xml)

Comment: I don't think so, because that question was about XML-less configuration of EhCache in **Spring**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not. Hibernate [EhCacheRegionFactory](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/4.3.8.Final/org/hibernate/cache/ehcache/EhCacheRegionFactory.java/?v=source) tries to load the `ehcache.xml` configuration upon loading:

```
String configurationResourceName = null;
if ( properties != null ) {
    configurationResourceName = (String) properties.get( NET_SF_EHCACHE_CONFIGURATION_RESOURCE_NAME );
}
if ( configurationResourceName == null || configurationResourceName.length() == 0 ) {
    final Configuration configuration = ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration();
    manager = new CacheManager( configuration );
}
else {
    final URL url = loadResource( configurationResourceName );
    final Configuration configuration = HibernateEhcacheUtils.loadAndCorrectConfiguration( url );
    manager = new CacheManager( configuration );
}
```

The `ehcache.xml` resource can be configured using the [net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/index.html#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set/co-hib_enable_second_level_cache_settings.html) property:

```
net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName=/name_of_ehcache.xml
```