# Using multiple cache implementations with Spring Cache

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot, spring-cache

I'm working on a `Spring Boot` app where I need to use both distributed (e.g. `Hazelcast`) and local (e.g. `Guava`) caches. Is there a way to configure Spring Cache to use both when using `@Cacheable` and decide which implementation is needed based on the cache name?

I tried with creating a configuration for both HZ and Guava defining the cache names inside, but Spring complains that it couldn't find the cache name that is supposed to handled by HZ. When I use exclusively HZ or Guava they work.

Comment: With [`CompositeCacheManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/support/CompositeCacheManager.html) it should be possible, but you will possibly have to disabled Boot's autoconfiguration (I am not that familiar with Boot).

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21992641/865403

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Which implementation is needed based on the cache name?

Not based on the cache name, but yes - based on the [CacheManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) it is possible. Declare one of them as `@Primary CacheManager`, as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/cache.properties" })
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CacheManager hazelcastCacheManager() {
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
        return new HazelcastCacheManager(client);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager guavaCacheManager() {
         GuavaCacheManager cacheManager = new GuavaCacheManager("mycache");
           CacheBuilder<Object, Object> cacheBuilder = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
           .maximumSize(100)
           .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
           cacheManager.setCacheBuilder(cacheBuilder);
           return cacheManager;
    }

}
```

and specify it at class level as:

```
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheManager="hazelcastCacheManager")
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements IEmployeeService {

}
```

or at method level as:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements IEmployeeService {

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "EMPLOYEE_", key = "#id", cacheManager= "guavaCacheManager")
    public Employee getEmployee(int id) {
        return new Employee(id, "A");
    }

}
```

If you have to stick with Cache name only, then you can multiple CacheManager.

Comment: I followed your solution but got this exception on startup:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CacheResolver specified, and no unique bean of type CacheManager found. Mark one as primary (or give it the name 'cacheManager') or declare a specific CacheManager to use, that serves as the default one.` I tried to use the name the error message mentions but it didn't help. Any idea on that?

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works perfectly! It's a shame that Spring doesn't cover this part properly in their docs as it's fairly simple once you get some guidelines.

Comment: @Arpit , @Balazs can we use both these cache managers in one method `@Cachable` ?

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik no, only one at a time, as cacheManager is a `String` instance in `@Cachable` and not `Array`.

Comment: As hazelcastCacheManager is annotated with @Primary so no need to specify cacheManager= "hazelcastCacheManager" specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options.

One is as @Arpit mentioned: Define multiple CacheManagers and specify it in either method-level annotations (@Cacheable, @CachePut, etc) or class-level annotations (@CacheConfig)

You can also create custom annotations:

```
@CacheConfig(cacheManager = "guavaCacheManager")
@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface GuavaCacheable {
}

@GuavaCacheable
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
}
```

And as the second option, you can create a custom cache resolver if your caching needs are complex.

You can look [here](https://github.com/isaolmez/spring-cache-samples/tree/master/spring-cache-custom) for a custom CacheResolver that manages multiple CacheManagers and supports enabling/disabling. But for most cases, CacheResolver is overkill.

Comment: hello, I used this way. But still, Spring cannot identify which cache manager to autowire into my service class. any help please?

Answer (score 0):

One can consider using

https://github.com/yatharthamishra0419/multimodule-cache

library for support of multiple caching system, this library is extensible,multi-module aware and support for various caching systems can be added in the framework.This also includes a annotation through which multiple sources can be used