# How to use spring boot 2 and ehcache 3 without xml?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache, ehcache-3

For now I have following config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class EhcacheConfig {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() throws URISyntaxException {
        return new JCacheCacheManager(Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager(
                getClass().getResource("/ehcache.xml").toURI(),
                getClass().getClassLoader()
        ));
    }
}
```

It refers to the following XML:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.ehcache.org/v3"
        xmlns:jsr107="http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd
            http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd">

    <cache alias="pow_cache">
        <key-type>org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey</key-type>
        <value-type>java.lang.Double</value-type>
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">15</ttl>
        </expiry>

        <listeners>
            <listener>
                <class>my.pack.CacheEventLogger</class>
                <event-firing-mode>ASYNCHRONOUS</event-firing-mode>
                <event-ordering-mode>UNORDERED</event-ordering-mode>
                <events-to-fire-on>CREATED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>EXPIRED</events-to-fire-on>
            </listener>
        </listeners>

        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">2</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">10</offheap>
        </resources>
    </cache>

</config>
```

And service look like this:

```
@Cacheable(value = "pow_cache", unless = "#pow==3||#result>100", condition = "#val<5")
public Double pow(int val, int pow) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(String.format("REAL invocation myService.pow(%s, %s)", val, pow));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    return Math.pow(val, pow);
}
```

It works properly but I want to get free of xml configuration.

I've read and tried to apply [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21944585/2674303)(last piece of code) But it works only for Ehcache 2 but I am going to use Eehcache 3

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: @Sambit it is not a duplicate. I mentioned that topic in my question. Please, be attentive

Comment: Thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As EhCache [seems to be JSR-107 compliant](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.0/107.html#getting-started-with-ehcache-3-jcache), you'll need to use it this way to have a programatic configuration:

```java
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() throws URISyntaxException {
    CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();  
    CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager();   

    CacheConfigurationBuilder<SimpleKey, Double> configuration = 
    CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey.class,
        java.lang.Double.class, 
        ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(2).offheap(10, MemoryUnit.MB))
        .withExpiry(Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration(new Duration(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)));

    Cache cache = cacheManager.createCache("pow_cache", configuration);
    cache.getRuntimeConfiguration().registerCacheEventListener(listener, EventOrdering.UNORDERED,
        EventFiring.ASYNCHRONOUS, EnumSet.of(EventType.CREATED, EventType.EXPIRED)); 
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Haven't tested it myself, but this should work for you.

Check out [this programatic sample with more configuration options](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/blob/master/basic/src/main/java/org/ehcache/sample/BasicProgrammatic.java) from the EhCache repo and the docs part on [how to register listeners programatically](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.0/cache-event-listeners.html) too.

Comment: where is resources(heap/offheap/disk) part?

Comment: Updated for your concrete case ;-)

Comment: From what packages are these classes? I'm trying to reuse this solution but unfortunately without success. Moreover when I try to use this code overriding `CachingConfigurer.cacheManager()` then I get error `Error creating bean with name 'cacheResolver' ... java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CacheManager is required`

Comment: How change memoryStoreEvictionPolicy to LFU programatically?

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution

```
@Bean
CacheManager getCacheManager() {

    CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
    CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager();

    CacheConfigurationBuilder<String, String> configurationBuilder =
            CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                    String.class, String.class,
                    ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(1000)
                                        .offheap(25, MemoryUnit.MB))
                                     .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.ofHours(3)));

    CacheEventListenerConfigurationBuilder asynchronousListener = CacheEventListenerConfigurationBuilder
            .newEventListenerConfiguration(new CacheEventLogger()
                    , EventType.CREATED, EventType.EXPIRED).unordered().asynchronous();

    //create caches we need
    cacheManager.createCache("productCatalogConfig",
                             Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(configurationBuilder.withService(asynchronousListener)));

    return cacheManager;
}
```

equivalent of :

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.ehcache.org/v3"
    xmlns:jsr107="http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd">

<cache alias="productCatalogConfig">
    <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
    <value-type>java.lang.String</value-type>
    <expiry>
        <ttl unit="seconds">1600</ttl>
    </expiry>

    <listeners>
        <listener>
            <class>com.klarna.config.CacheEventLogger</class>
            <event-firing-mode>ASYNCHRONOUS</event-firing-mode>
            <event-ordering-mode>UNORDERED</event-ordering-mode>
            <events-to-fire-on>CREATED</events-to-fire-on>
            <events-to-fire-on>EXPIRED</events-to-fire-on>
        </listener>
    </listeners>

    <resources>
        <heap unit="entries">1000</heap>
        <offheap unit="MB">25</offheap>
    </resources>
</cache>
```