# Ehcache - not terminating VM

Tags: java, ehcache

I have a simple one class test to load ehache 2.8.1

Everything is fine however if setting either diskPersistent="true" or overflowToDisk="true" then the VM never terminates.

I have tried setting the shutdown hook but this isn't fired as the thread used by Ehcache isn't a daemon so the vm never gets that far.

```
<ehcache 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
<diskStore path="/temp"/>
<defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="100" 
    eternal="false"
    overflowToDisk="false"
/>

<cache 
    name="resolveIpAddresses" 
    maxElementsInMemory="100000" 
    diskPersistent="true"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    eternal="false"         
    timeToLiveSeconds="3600"                
/>
</ehcache>
```

The ehcache is being managed by a spring 3.1.8 container with the beans

```
<cache:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache"/>
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:config-location="/ehcache.xml" p:shared="true"/>
```

Changing the disk settings to false works fine but obviously not great. How do I tell ehcache that the disk threads are daemon?

Comment: Related answers are available in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373431/ehcache-disk-store-unclean-shutdown

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a servlet container, you can use the servlet [ShutdownListener](http://ehcache.org/documentation/operations/shutdown#servletcontextlistener), otherwise it's possible to shutdown the disk threads by calling `CacheManager.getInstance().shutdown()` explicitly in the code.

The [Ehcache documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/operations/shutdown#the-shutdown-hook) says that the JVM shutdown hook will:

> shutdown the DiskStore. If the DiskStore is persistent, it will write the entries and index > to disk.

The shutdown hook can be explicitly called with a call to `System.exit()`, in addition to being called when the last non-daemon thread shutdown.